# $scope.myArrayOfObjects.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, push, angular-material

I need help please. 
I'm working with AngularJS and Angular Material. I try push a object to an array, but it sends me a message "$scope.myArrayOfObject.push is not a function".

My code:

```js
controller("ClientesCTRL",function($scope,$http,$q,$timeout,$location, datosFactory, userFactory, $mdDialog){
  $scope.clientes = [];
  user = userFactory.getUser();
  if(user){
    $scope.selected = [];



      $scope.query = {
        filter : '',
       order: 'rut',
       limit: 5,
       page: 1
      };

      var data =  {'op':1, 'rut' : user.rut};
      $http.post('functions/ClientesCTRL.php', data)
      .success(function(results){
        console.log(results);
        $scope.clientes = results;
      });




      $scope.onpagechange = function(page, limit) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();

       $timeout(function () {
         deferred.resolve();
       }, 2000);

       return deferred.promise;
      };

      $scope.onorderchange = function(order) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();

       $timeout(function () {
         deferred.resolve();
       }, 2000);

       return deferred.promise;
      };

      $scope.verContacto = function(){
        datosFactory.setClienteContacto($scope.selected[0]);
        $location.path("/contactos")
      };


      $scope.eliminarCliente = function(ev) {
      // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
      var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Eliminar Clientes')
            .content('Estás seguro?')
            .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .ok('Eliminar')
            .cancel('Cancelar');
      $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
        alert("Cliente eliminado");
      }, function() {

      });
    };


      $scope.addCliente = function(ev){
          $mdDialog.show({
          controller: AddClienteController,
          templateUrl: 'addClienteForm.html',
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          targetEvent: ev,
          clickOutsideToClose:true
        })
        .then(function(c) {
          console.log(c);


          var data =  {'op':3, 'cl' : c, 'user':user};
          console.log(data);
          $scope.clientes.push(c);
          $http.post('functions/ClientesCTRL.php', data)
          .success(function(results){
            if(results){
              alert("Cliente agregado");
              $scope.clientes = [];
              $scope.clientes.push(c);
            }else{
              alert("Error al agregar cliente");
            }
            console.log(results);
          });

        }, function() {
          $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
      };

      function AddClienteController($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {
        $http.post("functions/UsuarioCTRL.php",{'op':14})
        .success(function(results){
          if(results !== null){
            $scope.formaspago = results;
          }
        });
        $scope.hide = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $mdDialog.cancel();
        };
        $scope.btnAddCliente = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide($scope.addCliente);
        };
      };
    }
```

```html
<md-dialog style="width:600px;" aria-label="Agregar Cliente"  ng-cloak>
  <form>
    <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h1 style="letter-spacing:3px; text-transform:uppercase"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Agregar Cliente/Empresa</h1>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
        X
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ">
    <div class="md-dialog-content">

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Rut Cliente/Empresa</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.rut" required="true">
        </md-input-container>



        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Razón Social</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.razon_social" required="true">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Nombre de fantasía</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.fantasia" required="true">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Giro</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.giro" required="true">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Teléfono</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.telefono">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Dirección</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.direccion" required="true">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Comuna</label>
          <input ng-model="addCliente.comuna" required="true">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Observación</label>
          <textarea ng-model="addCliente.observacion" rows="4"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Forma de pago</label>
          <md-select ng-model="addCliente.forma_pago">
          <md-option ng-repeat="fp in formaspago" value="{{fp.forma}}">
            {{fp.forma}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
        </md-input-container>

    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
  <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button ng-click="btnAddCliente()" style="margin-right:20px;" >
      Agregar Cliente
    </md-button>
  </div>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Help me please.
Grettings!

Comment: Which line is causing the problem

Comment: $scope.clientes.push(c);
Inside function addCliente

Answer (score 1):

```
  var data =  {'op':1, 'rut' : user.rut};
  $http.post('functions/ClientesCTRL.php', data)
  .success(function(results){
    console.log(results);
    $scope.clientes = results;
  });
```

are you sure the $scope.clientes is still a array?

Comment: the second line set array on $scope.clientes

Comment: but it equal to  result later

Comment: $scope.clientes = results;  if results isn't a array .

Answer (score 0):

Your array may not be an array anymore, you've pointed `clientes = results`,  you'll need to push `results` into `clientes` if it isn't an array.  `$scope.clientes.push(results)`

Also, what is "c"?

Are you trying to push the value attached to `cl` in your `data` object?

In which case you'll have to map to it via - `$scope.clientes.push(data.cl)`

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try

Comment: do you mean your code works without any changes made to it?  Or it now works with the suggested changes...?